# HTML won't apply TailwindCSS stylesheet

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to build a web-app with Go and applying styling with tailwindCSS. After following the installation [instructions](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation) (CLI, Linux), there is no change in the style of the served page (specifically the `text-3xl font-bond underline` h1 class).

./templates/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link  href="/assets/css/output.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Go-lift</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Workout: <h1>
    <p>{{ .Date }}</p>
    <h2>Exercises</h2>
    {{ range .Exercises }}
        <h3>{{ .Name }} : </h3>
        {{ range .Sets }}
            <p>Set: {{ .SetNumber }} - Weight: {{ .Weight }} - Reps: {{ .Reps }}</p>
        {{ end }}
    {{ end }}
   
    <h1 class = "text-3xl font-bold underline">
        Hello World!
    </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

./tailwindconfig.js

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["./templates/**/*.{html,js}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

./assets/css/input.css

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

I have checked all paths, and tailwind is successfully creating an output.css file at /assets/css/output.css, however no change occurs when linking this stylesheet in the HTML template. I've tried mocing this output.css file around, including in the root of the template file, with no luck.

Comment: When you use the DevTools in your web browser, can you verify the CSS file actually gets fetched successfully from the server? I mean, we need to first separate the problem space to try to pinpoint the location of your problem.

Comment: It's not getting fetched correctly, and I think I've realised where I've gone wrong. I interpreted the `href` path according to the internal project directory structure, but I think I've realised it appends the path the base url to fetch it? I've found [this project](https://github.com/jritsema/go-htmx-tailwind-example/blob/main/main.go) and it looks like they serve the CSS file with Go's file server method. Currently implementing this, and will provide a more concise solution once I've got it working.

Answer (score 0):

CSS file wasn't being served by the Go server. Fixed by using http.ServeFile(response, request, .) to serve CSS to a url which is fetched by the HTML template. Note, the `.` prefix must be used to define a path relative to the file being executed (this confused me for longer than I'd like to admit).

addition to main.go:

```
    http.HandleFunc("/styles/tailwind", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        http.ServeFile(w, r, "./css/output.css")
    })
```